# Creating an App Using React Native for Android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I'm very newbie to ReactJs. I'm following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969) tutorial.
but I'm getting error like:

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\harshalb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-r
emotes_templates --mirror git@github.com:facebook/react.git C:\Users\harshalb\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-
a74af502d8e5579c42e0f6b0488923ce: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\harshalb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-r
emotes_templates --mirror git@github.com:facebook/react.git C:\Users\harshalb\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-
a74af502d8e5579c42e0f6b0488923ce: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Dictionary\npm-debug.log
`npm install --save react-native` failed

can anybody tell me where I'm getting wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) for windows with check the option "Run Git from Windows Command Prompt".
[image]

Navigate to the Environmental Variables Editor (instructions) and find the Path variable in the “System Variables” section. Click Edit… and paste the URL of Git to the end of that string.
for me its `;C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Getting your Android environment setup is time consuming and am act of tenacity. Took me 3 hrs. I would recommend that you first ensure you get setup right via the official documentation. Since you are on windows, you may have additional challenges. Don't be discouraged! Getting setup is the toughest part. See this link for starts... https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content